# Premade sed string not interpreting string properly

Tags: bash, sed

I have code that is meant to find line numbers in a file where 2 different files are equivalent, and then remove all but those line numbers from one of the files. To do so, I made a pre-made sed string I want to run in sed, but I am getting the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unknown command: `;'
```

My premade sed string looks like so

```
echo ${_sedstr}
1;2;7;11;12;13;15;17;22!d
```

My intention was to then use this variable in a sed command to remove all lines except those in the string within the file ${_edit}

```
sed -i.bak -e ${_sedstr} ${_edit}
```

I've tried all combinations of placing single / double quotes around ${_sedstr} and escaping the quotes with a backslash '\', but I still seem to have an issue with the code running as intended.

---

An example of what I am trying to achieve would be say ${_edit} looked like this:

```
hello
my
name
is
John
Doe
```

With the expression `sed -i.bak -e '1;2;4!d' ${_edit}`, I would expect the file to output to

```
hello
my
is
```

Deleting all lines besides 1, 2, and 4.

Comment: Your `sed` syntax is wrong - try `sed -e '1;2;7;11;12;13;15;17;22!d' "${_edit}"` and you'll see that this fails too. It might be useful for you to explain in your question what it is you're trying to achieve with this command. With an example.

Comment: @roaima Thank you, I added the example to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the correct `sed` syntax.

It should be `sed '1d;2d;7d'` not `sed '1;2;7d'`

To delete all but 1, 2, 7, use `sed -e 1b -e 2b -e 7b -e d` (you can't use `;` to separate `b` commands portably/POSIXly, but you could use newline).

So:

```
sed_script='1d;2d;7d'
sed -i.back -e "$sed_script" -- "$_edit"
```

Or:

```
sed_script='
  1b
  2b
  7b
  d
'
sed -i.back -e "$sed_script" -- "$_edit"
```

Parameter expansions should be quoted. See [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694). And don't forget the `--` option delimiter. It's `cmd -- "$arg"`, you don't want `cmd "$option_or_arg"` here.

For a large number of lines to keep/delete, with GNU `awk`, you could use:

```
LINES_TO_KEEP='1;2;7;...' gawk -i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk -e '
  BEGIN {
    split(ENVIRON["LINES_TO_KEEP"], a, ";")
    for (i in a) keep[a[i]]
  }
  FNR in keep' -E /dev/null "$_edit"
```

(that one doesn't work for a file called `-` though; you'd have to use `_edit=./-` instead of `_edit=-`).

**Do not use `-i inplace`** as `gawk` tries to load the `inplace` extension (as `inplace` or `inplace.awk`) from the current working directory first, where someone could have planted malware. The path of the `inplace` extension supplied with `gawk` may vary with the system, see the output of `gawk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["AWKPATH"]}'`

Comment: This comment I believe addressed my misunderstanding the best, but honorable mention bu5hman, because I did not care about the ordering so it was a very simple one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

A little off piste from `sed` but since that has been answered already...if you are not worried about the order, only pairing lines which are the same, you could ...

```
join <(sort file1) <(sort file2) > matchedlines
```

Doesn't require a knowledge of the line numbers and doesn't need an array passing into `awk`.